# Disk size varies - MooseFs

Tags: performance, disk-space, cpu-usage, storage-spaces, iowait

I have 4 moosefs chunkservers with 8 2.7 TB storage on each, I mount them using mfsmount and then export with nfs. Recently I noticed high iowait on my chunkservers, then huge mount size drops, see the graphs. 
[image]

Comment: which version of MooseFS do you use? Why do you re-share MFS via NFS? Do you **really** need it? Your charts are very compressed, it is hard to see anything in legend.
Could you post a bigger image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this problem was the RAM on mfs server, it started to use 50% of swap, when I increased the RAM, everything started to work as expected, but still high iowait exists on chunk server, I guess that we should move from jbod to some kind of raid.

Answer (score 1):

About JBOD moosefs.com website says as follows (in "Best practices"):
(https://moosefs.com/documentation/best-practices.html#jbod)

> JBOD and XFS for Chunkservers
>
> We recommend to connect to Chunkserver(s) JBODs. Just format the drive as XFS and mount on e.g.
> `/mnt/chunk01, /mnt/chunk02, ...` and put these paths into
> `/etc/mfs/mfschunkserver.cfg`. That's all.
>
> We recommend such configuration mainly because of two reasons:
>
> MooseFS has a mechanism of checking if the hard disk is in a good
> condition or not. MooseFS can discover broken disks, replicate the
> data and mark such disks as damaged. The situation is different with
> RAID: MooseFS algorithms do not work with RAIDs, therefore corrupted
> RAID arrays may be falsely reported as healthy/ok.
>
> The other aspect is time of replication. Let's assume you have goal
> set to 2 for the whole MooseFS instance. If one 2 TiB drive breaks,
> the replication (from another copy) will last about 40-60 minutes. If
> one big RAID (e.g. 36 TiB) becomes corrupted, replication can last
> even for 12-18 hours. Until the replication process is finished, some
> of your data is in danger, because you have only one valid copy. If
> another disk or RAID fails during that time, some of your data may be
> irrevocably lost. So the longer replication period puts your data in
> greater danger.